# How do I convert from camel case to dashed and dashed to camel case

Tags: javascript

1) How do you convert a camel case string like `"backgroundColor"` to dashed case like `"background-color"` and

2) How do you convert dashed case `"background-color"` to camel case `"backgroundColor"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the two functions I use:

```js
function camelToDash(str){
  return str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function($1){return "-"+$1.toLowerCase();});
}

function dashToCamel(str){
  return str.replace(/(\-[a-z])/g, function($1){return $1.toUpperCase().replace('-','');});
}

console.log('camelToDash ->', camelToDash('camelToDash'));
console.log('dash-to-camel ->', dashToCamel('dash-to-camel'));
```

And, in ES6:

```js
const camelToDash = str => str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, val => `-${val.toLowerCase()}`);

const dashToCamel = str => str.replace(/(\-[a-z])/g, val => val.toUpperCase().replace('-',''));

console.log('camelToDash ->', camelToDash('camelToDash'));
console.log('dash-to-camel ->', dashToCamel('dash-to-camel'));
```