# How does Angular 2 handles attributes with camelCase

Tags: javascript, angular

I've been working on a pet project for web components. I am experimenting with a data binding library of my own. So far I managed to create all the essential functionalities I would typically use for angular 2 templates, the if, the for, the class and the data input for web components. One limitation that I hit so far is that html attributes names are normalized by the browser to lower case.

So when you I use:

```
var attribute = element.getAttribute(attributeName);
```

I will receive the original `attribute.nodeValue` in `attribute.nodeName`. That means my current syntax is not the best looking one because I use the attribute value to store the source property name in the original case.

`p-data="mockDataProp, customInput"`

I would like to have something like this

`(mockDataProp)="customInput"`

But what I get in the `nodeName`property is `mockdataprop`. So far, the only idea I have is to use attribute normalisation similar to AngularJS. Kebab case to camel case. Another one would be to use a wrapper over `innerHTML` and regex the hell out of it... which I suspect is not that wise.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you consider using element.dataset ?

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll read a bit more about dataset and than I'll be back with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how Angular does it but I do know that attributes are always lower case. Try using something like `el.innerHTML='<b myAttr="true">b</b>';` or `el.setAttribute('myAttr', 'true');` and the attribute will be converted to lowercase.

What many libraries do is us the dashed case to camel case conversion to let them gain uppercase attribute names. So `'my-attr'` would become `'myAttr'` and `'inner-h-t-m-l'` becomes `'innerHTML'`

Here is a simple routine to convert from dashed case to camel case:
[How do I convert from camel case to dashed and dashed to camel case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932847/how-do-i-convert-from-camel-case-to-dashed-and-dashed-to-camel-case)